# Google Map setCenter to a newly clicked area

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code. In the section regarding the 'click' event I want to get the lang of the clicked-point but I have been unable to do so so far. What shall I do?

PROBLEM: I need to `setCenter` of the map to the newly clicked area.

```
<div id='map-container' style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">


var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.7, 51.3999)
  };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container'),
      mapOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    title: 'موقعیت خود را انتخاب کنید'
  });





    google.maps.event.addListener(document.getElementById('map-container'), 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(10);
    map.setCenter(35.7, 51.3999);
    console.log(marker.getPosition());
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) To get the lat/lng of the point which is being clicked in Google Maps, you have to use **`click`** *`eventListener`* of Google Maps like

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {

  });
```

(2) Then to get the position of the maps that is being clicked,

```
event.latLng    //returns the position
event.latLng.ob //returns lat
event.latLng.pb //returns lng
```

(3) Now using **`setCenter(pos)`**, mark the clicked area as map's center like

```
map.setCenter(event.latLng);
```

Finally,

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    map.setCenter(event.latLng);
  });
```

### [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/yV6xv/3290/)

**EDIT:**  *can you please also tell me how at the same time move the red marker to the newly clicked area?*

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
        marker.setPosition(event.latLng); //set the position to marker
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition()); //Now set marker to map's center
    });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/yV6xv/3291/)

Comment: Wonderful...then can you please also tell me how at the same time move the red marker to the newly clicked area?

Comment: Use event.latLng.lat() and event.latLng.lng() To get the position, not the properties, as they can change their name!